# Dynamic Assets location path for entries & Commerce

Tags: assets

I have a Matrix that I use for both Entries and Commerce Products. Inside of that Matrix is an Assets field.

Currently, I have `{owner.parent.uri ?? owner.section.handle}/{owner.slug}` which works perfectly for Entries. Assets are organised perfectly for my site.

How can I get add a check for Commerce in there? Something like:

```
{owner.product.type ?? owner.parent.uri ?? owner.section.handle}/{owner.slug}
```

Is that possible? Otherwise, do I have to use a long-hand if/else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just decided to go with `{uri}` for all my asset paths now. Works well :D